# Limit foreach to output 4 results

Tags: php, foreach

someone please help to limit the below foreach code to output 4 results only and in desc order. Thank you very much!

```
foreach( $users_who_like as $id ) :

if ( $id != $user_id )
$output .= ' &middot <a href="' . bp_core_get_user_domain( $id ) . '" title="' . bp_core_get_user_displayname( $id ) . '">' . bp_core_get_user_displayname( $id ) . '</a>';

endforeach;
```

Comment: We don't write the code for you. Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: At this point you'd be better off using a regular for-loop.

Comment: You have to provide the mysql code that brings out these results

Comment: fetching only four result would be better option or in other way appropiate option to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `count` and check if it's `4` 
like this

```
$count = 4; 

foreach( $users_who_like as $id ){

if ( $id != $user_id )
$output .= ' &middot <a href="' . bp_core_get_user_domain( $id ) . '" title="'.bp_core_get_user_displayname( $id ) . '">' . bp_core_get_user_displayname( $id ) .'</a>';

 if(count <=0)
 break; //will break if statement and foreach

 $count--; // reduce it by one

}
```

Comment: Hi, I got unexpected T_DEC error on this line count--; this code works without the count--; but it does not show any result if it is more than 4.

Comment: missing a `$` on `count--`.

Comment: hmm it only output 1 result actually, regardless of how many total.

Comment: Oh it works nows, filling in the missing $ for count. THANK YOU very much! Mido, Marc B and everyone here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#delete $user_id from array $users_who_like , we would not compare it any times

$users_list = array_diff($users_who_like,array($user_id));

#sort the array 

rsort($users_list);

#set the limit we want to show

$limit = 4;

#use for better than foreach 

for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
    $id = $users_list[$i];

    #do sometings

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it when selecting the data from database.
Use `ODER BY ... DESC` to order, `LIMIT` to limit and `WHERE` to filter out current user.