# How do you limit the output of a foreach?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to create a website where one can bookmark properties and then only a couple of them get displayed on the homepage. 
I already have the list of the bookmarked properties working using cookies, but im having problems with limiting the output when it comes to the display on the hoempage.

```
<h2>Previously seen properties</h2>
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE["bookmark"]))
    {//
        $total = 0;
        $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['bookmark']);//removes backslashes
        $bookmark_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);//converts JSON string to PHP variable
        foreach($bookmark_data as $keys => $values)
        {
    ?> <!---what will be displayed--->



        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px;width:300px; height:300px;">
            <img src="../01_Global/assets/img/Houses/'. $row['Image'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="productpage.php"> <?php echo $values["property_name"]; ?></a></strong></p>
            <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" > <?php echo $values["property_price"]; ?></h4>


        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    echo '';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you need to break the loop at a certain number? is that what you are asking?

Comment: You can iterate a number up to your preferred limit and then use ```break``` to end the loop

Comment: What does your data structure look like? If it is a standard numerically indexed array, you can simply check the key of the current items - is it greater than x, break out of the loop. If not, then make your own counter variable, increase it by one in each loop iteration, and check that.

Comment: Is this what you want to have ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918220/limit-foreach-to-output-4-results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit foreach to output 4 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918220/limit-foreach-to-output-4-results)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

So a simple counter maintained in your existing loop would do it

```
<h2>Previously seen properties</h2>
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["bookmark"]))
{
    $total = 0;
    $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['bookmark']);//removes backslashes
    $bookmark_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);//converts JSON string to PHP variable

    // initialise the counter
    $cnt = 0;

    foreach($bookmark_data as $keys => $values) {
        if ($cnt == 2) {
            // only show 2
            break;
        }
        $cnt++;

?> 
    <!---what will be displayed--->

        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px;width:300px; height:300px;">
            <img src="../01_Global/assets/img/Houses/'. $row['Image'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
            <p align="center"><strong><a href="productpage.php"> <?php echo $values["property_name"]; ?></a></strong></p>
            <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" > <?php echo $values["property_price"]; ?></h4>
        </div>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter and condition to break out a loop:

```
<?php
$one_to_five = range(1, 5);
$break_out   = 3;    
$counter     = 0;
foreach($one_to_five as $num) {
    $counter++;
    if($counter > $break_out)
        break;
    echo $num, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```